# UIDatePicker in UIActionSheet on iPad

Tags: iphone, ipad, uidatepicker, uiactionsheet

In the iPhone version of my app, I have a `UIDatePicker` in a `UIActionSheet`. It appears correctly. I am now setting up the iPad version of the app, and the same `UIActionSheet` when viewed on the iPad appears as a blank blank box.

Here is the code I am using:

```
UIDatePicker *datePickerView = [[UIDatePicker alloc] init];
    datePickerView.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDate;

    self.dateActionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Choose a Follow-up Date"
                                                   delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil 
                                     destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Done", nil];

    [self.dateActionSheet showInView:self.view];
    [self.dateActionSheet addSubview:datePickerView];
    [self.dateActionSheet sendSubviewToBack:datePickerView];
    [self.dateActionSheet setBounds:CGRectMake(0,0,320, 500)];

    CGRect pickerRect = datePickerView.bounds;
    pickerRect.origin.y = -95;
    datePickerView.bounds = pickerRect;
```

Comment: Question helped me understand how Apple expected users to use Popovers and ActionSheets on the iPad much better than their documentation did. Thank you.

Comment: Check my answer it may use full to you.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/7343106/815179

Comment: Thanks @Narayana , but this question was from 6 years ago :-)

Comment: @Chris yes my question also 6 years ago i have updated my answer with swift so added this comment.

Comment: Check this answer [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7341835/uidatepicker-in-uipopover/7343106#7343106](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7341835/uidatepicker-in-uipopover/7343106#7343106)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I ended up creating a separate segment of code for the iPad Popover:

```
//build our custom popover view
UIViewController* popoverContent = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
UIView* popoverView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 344)];
popoverView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

datePicker.frame = CGRectMake(0, 44, 320, 300);

[popoverView addSubview:toolbar];
[popoverView addSubview:datePicker];
popoverContent.view = popoverView;

//resize the popover view shown
//in the current view to the view's size
popoverContent.contentSizeForViewInPopover = CGSizeMake(320, 244);

//create a popover controller
UIPopoverController *popoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:popoverContent];

//present the popover view non-modal with a
//refrence to the button pressed within the current view
[popoverController presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem 
                          permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny 
                                          animated:YES];

//release the popover content
[popoverView release];
[popoverContent release];
```

Comment: This is great, however I get the empty white box above the date picker which is expected. Does anyone know how I can use this real estate somehow? I'd like to set a title here.

Comment: @AbuZubair you might just need to set a negative value on a CGRect so that a Label will appear in the unused space - hacky but it might just work. :-/